# Bluetooth low energy file transfer

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have some questions about bluetooth low energy,

I want to transfer file via bluetooth low energy. (BLE)
I know that I can only transfer 20bytes in one packet,
so I split file into multi packet!

And my question is that,

when I transfer one packet, if its in bad signal, and loss something,
will BLE process it? (e.g. auto resend, or do something let me know it?)

Or receiver should tell me the packet is wrong(if their is checksum in packet).(e.g. send NACK to me)

I want to know that, it depends on how to design flow chart and transfer speed rate.

Should I handle transfer issue by myself? or bottom layer will do it!

P.S. I'm developing the application on Android platform.

Comment: why oh why??  If you have a nail do you use a screwdriver?  Most Android devices with BLE also have regular Bluetooth and that's what you'd use to do a file transfer.  If you're just trying to transfer files in the most painful way possible, then have one device flash Morse code on the screen and the other interpret it via the camera.

Comment: There are many perfectly good reasons for wanting to send data over BLE, including the simplicity of pairing/connections. You can achieve speeds of up to around 8 kb/s so for small files (i.e. 100-200 kb), its much faster than first going through the standard bluetooth pairing process to transfer a file

Comment: @BrockAmhurst: The 8 kb/s you are talking about: Is this speed possible using GATT or a protocol of a lower level?

Answer (score 3):

As a BLE enthusiast I must say BLE is possibly worst way to use to transfer data.For further information , please refer to documentation.

> Data Transfers – Bluetooth Smart (low energy) supports very short data packets >(8 octet minimum up to 27 octets maximum) that are transferred at 1 Mbps.
>
> Robustness – Bluetooth Smart (low energy) uses a strong 24 bit CRC on all packets ensuring the maximum robustness against interference

http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/low-energy-tech-info.aspx
Edit:Typo.